# Python Pandas - Merge between condition

Tags: python, pandas, merge, conditional-statements, between

I have 2 dataframes in python pandas

Dataframe 1

```
User_id  zipcode

1        12345

2        23456

3        34567
```

Dataframe 2

```
ZipCodeLowerBound ZipCodeUpperBound Region

10000             19999             1

20000             29999             2

30000             39999             3
```

How can I map in the Region to dataframe 1 with the condition `if(df1.zipcode>=df2.ZipCodeLowerBound and df1.zipcode<=df2.ZipCodeUpperBound)` using pandas merge

Answer (score 2):

This gives a column per region and a mask of each zipcode belonging to that region or not:

```
df2 = df2.set_index('Region')
mask = df2.apply(lambda r: df1.zipcode.between(r['ZipCodeLowerBound'],
                                               r['ZipCodeUpperBound']),
                 axis=1).T
mask
Out[103]: 
Region      1      2      3
0        True  False  False
1       False   True  False
2       False  False   True
```

Then you can use that matrix against its own column names to apply it as a mask and find back the region:

```
mask.dot(mask.columns)
Out[110]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'User_id': [1,2,3],
                    'zipcode':[12345,23456,34567]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ZipCodeLowerBound': [10000,20000,30000],
                    'ZipCodeUpperBound': [19999,29999,39999],
                    'Region': [1,2,3]})

region = []
for i in range(len(df1.zipcode)):
    region.append(int(df2[(df2.ZipCodeLowerBound <= df1.zipcode[i]) & (df2.ZipCodeUpperBound >= df1.zipcode[i])]['Region']))
df1['Region'] = region

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
   User_id  zipcode  Region
0        1    12345       1
1        2    23456       2
2        3    34567       3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1['Region'] = df1.User_id
df1.merge(df2, on='Region')
```

you can merge both dataset if you will have the same columns in both dataframes,

well thats just an example how you can merge it, you can put your condition and try it

this is what output will be after merging it

```
   User_id  zipcode Region  ZipCodeLowerBound   ZipCodeUpperBound
0   1        12345     1         10000             19999
1   2        23456     2         20000             29999
2   3        34567     3         30000             39999
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), and is efficient for range joins as well, and is better than a naive cross join:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
# you can also install the dev version for the latest
# including the ability to use numba for faster performance
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git

import janitor
import pandas as pd

(df2
.conditional_join(
    df1, 
    ('ZipCodeLowerBound', 'zipcode', '<='), 
    ('ZipCodeUpperBound', 'zipcode', '>='))
.loc(axis=1)['User_id', 'zipcode', 'Region']
)

   User_id  zipcode  Region
0        1    12345       1
1        2    23456       2
2        3    34567       3
```

With the `dev` version, you can select the columns as well:

```py
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git

import janitor
import pandas as pd

(df2
.conditional_join(
    df1, 
    ('ZipCodeLowerBound', 'zipcode', '<='), 
    ('ZipCodeUpperBound', 'zipcode', '>='),
    df_columns = 'Region')
)

   Region  User_id  zipcode
0       1        1    12345
1       2        2    23456
2       3        3    34567
```