# Identifying events from time series

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, data-analysis

I have a time series for visibility data that contains half-hourly measurements of visibility. A fog event is defined when the visibility falls below 1 km and the fog event ends when the visibility exceeds 1 Km. Please find the code attached below. I intend to find out the number of such fog events and the duration of each such fog event.

```py
from IPython.display import display
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['visibility.csv']))

df.set_index('Unnamed: 0',inplace=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df=df.interpolate(method='linear', limit_direction='forward')
display(df)


Unnamed: 0          visibility_km
2016-01-01 00:00:00 0.595456
2016-01-01 00:30:00 0.595456
2016-01-01 01:00:00 0.595456
2016-01-01 01:30:00 0.595456
2016-01-01 02:00:00 0.595456
... ...
2020-12-31 21:30:00 0.925370
2020-12-31 22:00:00 0.901230
2020-12-31 22:30:00 0.804670
2020-12-31 23:00:00 0.804670
2020-12-31 23:30:00 0.692016

# FOG Events

fog_events=df[df<1.0].count()
print('no. of fog events',fog_events)
no. of fog events 10318
```

But it simply gives the number of times the visibility drops below 1 km and not the number of fog events.

Comment: Please share your entire code, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's easier for us to help you if you make your data copy & pasteable rather than an image. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315997/python-pandas-merge-between-condition) as an example and please edit your question accordingly

Comment: @erwanlfrt thanks for the suggestion!!

Comment: @HS-nebula Thanks! I have edited it.

Comment: @NathanMisan I think this an algorithm problem. ```fog_events=df[df<1.0].count()``` increments fog_events each time df is lower than 1.0. 

But you want to count each fog event. If I understand correctly a fog event starts when visibility is lower than 1.0 and it ends when visibility is greater than 1.0.

Maybe a while loop can be used... If you can share with us ```visibility.csv``` I would be able to give you an answer.

Comment: I think this question is pretty useful because I think it's a decently common problem (or will be). I couldn't find a direct duplicate anywhere or anything quite as similar. After the question was reformatted, it's much clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create sample time series data like this:

```
import pandas as pd

tdf = pd.DataFrame({'Time':pd.date_range(start='1/1/2016', periods=11, freq='30s'),
                   'Visibility_km': [0.56, 0.75, 0.99, 1.01, 1.1, 1.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 1.2, 1.3]})
```

Data in this format makes it easier to copy and paste your problem. To get the total number of fog events and their durations, start by creating a column for the events and one to mark when the event starts and ends

```
# Create column to mark duration of events
tdf['fog_event'] = (tdf['Visibility_km'] < 1.).astype(int)
# Create column to mark event start and end
tdf['event_diff'] = tdf['fog_event'] != tdf['fog_event'].shift(1)
print(tdf)

               Time     Visibility_km   fog_event   event_diff
0   2016-01-01 00:00:00     0.56              1     True
1   2016-01-01 00:00:30     0.75              1     False
2   2016-01-01 00:01:00     0.99              1     False
3   2016-01-01 00:01:30     1.01              0     True
4   2016-01-01 00:02:00     1.10              0     False
5   2016-01-01 00:02:30     1.30              0     False
6   2016-01-01 00:03:00     0.50              1     True
7   2016-01-01 00:03:30     0.60              1     False
8   2016-01-01 00:04:00     0.70              1     False
9   2016-01-01 00:04:30     1.20              0     True
10  2016-01-01 00:05:00     1.30              0     False
```

### Now you can get the events in two ways:

The first way doesn't use Pandas and was the original way I grouped the events by.

```
from itertools import groupby

groups = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(tdf.fog_event.values)]
fog_durations = np.array([sum(g) for g in groups])

duration_each_event = fog_durations[fog_durations != 0]
total_fog_events = sum(fog_durations != 0)

print(duration_each_event)
array([3, 3])
print(total_fog_events)
2
```

To do it using Pandas, you can group by the cumulative sum of the event difference

```
fdf = tdf.groupby([tdf['event_diff'].cumsum(), 'fog_event']).size()
fdf = fdf.reset_index(name = 'duration').rename(columns = {'event_diff': 'index'})

duration_each_event = fdf.loc[fdf['fog_event'] == 1, 'duration'].values
total_fog_events = fdf.loc[fdf['fog_event'] == 1, 'fog_event'].sum()

print(duration_each_event)
[3, 3]
print(total_fog_events)
2
```

Assuming the time interval between measurements doesn't change (i.e. always measured 30 seconds apart), you can multiply `duration_each_event` by 30 (for seconds) or 0.5 (for minutes) to get the duration in time units.